# Generate a PDF document from a webpage with style intact

Tags: css, itext, pdf-generation

I am using the iTextSharp library to convert a web page to a PDF document.
Although the document is successfully generated, the CSS applied on the webpage is not being applied in the PDF.

1. I take the HTML Markup and save it as a text file.
2. After that, I access that file and put the content into a string.
3. That markup gets converted in webpage and then into PDF.
4. But I am not able to apply any css to it.

Example Code:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Gridhtml = Gridhtml.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/HtmlTable/HtmlTableMarkup.txt"),Gridhtml);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/HtmlTable/HtmlTableMarkup.txt"));
    Document pdfdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4,10f,10f,100f,0f);
    PdfWriter pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc,stream);
    pdfdoc.Open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfw,pdfdoc,sr);
    pdfdoc.Close();
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "applicationpdf", "Grid.pdf");
}
```

How can I obtain the PDF with the same styling as the webpage?

Comment: You are using XML Worker. XML Worker is iText 5 technology. Please consider upgrading to iText 7 and pdfHTML. Take a look at [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/secret/pTMelvf4xqRtw) to see some code samples and screen shots of HTML / PDF documents that involve all kinds of CSS (inline, header CSS, external CSS). New in pdfHTML: support for media queries, support for `@page`, and much more.

Comment: Thank you @BrunoLowagie Sir , I ll try this for sure , thank you very much

Comment: @deepakdubey Please also consider that you might have to provide information to the converter concerning the base URL of the HTML if it references external resources via relative URLs, e.g. your css file if your CSS information are contained in an external file.